# jQuery animation stop on specif div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a horizontal style Roulette. The issue is that it does not stop on correct div on other resolutions than on 1920x1080

Currently the jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#roll").click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }

        $("#roll").html("Rolling...").addClass("disabled");

        var lineArrays = ['2985px', '2995px', '3005px', '3015px', '3025px', '3035px', '3045px', '3055px', '3065px', '3075px', '3085px', '3095px', '3100px'];

        var landLine = lineArrays[Math.floor(Math.random() * lineArrays.length)];
        console.log(landLine);

        $(".imageBox").animate({
            right: landLine
        }, {
            duration: 10500,
            easing: 'easeOutQuint'
        });



    });
});
```

So it gets random position from `var lineArrays` and then stop on that.

HTML looks like this:

```
  <div class="imageBox" id="1"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="2"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="3"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="4"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="5"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="6"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="7"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="8"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="9"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="10"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="11"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="12"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="13"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="14"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="15"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="16"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="17"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="18"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="19"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="20"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="21"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="22"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="23"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="24"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="24"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="25"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="26"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="27"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox imageBoxW" id="28"> <img src="image here"> </div> // this is the div where it stops on 1920x1080 resolution
  <div class="imageBox" id="29"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="30"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="31"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="32"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="33"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="34"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="35"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="36"> <img src="image here"> </div>
```

So it should stop on `<div class="imageBox imageBoxW" id="28"> <img src="image here"> </div>` but i haven't figured out how that would be possible.

I hope i get help from here.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? Why should animation stop at `<div class="imageBox imageBoxW" id="28"> <img src="image here"> </div>`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah sure wait a while and I'll create it. And because on different resolutions it does not stop on correct div.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it should stop randomly on an X width based on that lineArrays or if it can be stopped at a random element. I added a bit of code to get a random element and to add the class imageBoxw into that random element, maybe you can make it stop based on that selection. Once you click the word click lol the class name is added to the element, check dev tools.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#roll").click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }

        $("#roll").html("Rolling...").addClass("disabled");

        var lineArrays = ['2985px', '2995px', '3005px', '3015px', '3025px', '3035px', '3045px', '3055px', '3065px', '3075px', '3085px', '3095px', '3100px'];

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("imageBox");
       // console.log(elements); // 37 elements with that classname
       //Select a random element index
    var randElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length);
        
        //Get the id of that element and add a class to it
        var elementId = elements[randElement].id
        $('#'+ elementId +'').addClass('imageBoxW');
        //console.log(elements[randElement]);
        //STOP ANIMATION ON THAT RANDOM ELEMENT?
        
        var landLine = lineArrays[Math.floor(Math.random() * lineArrays.length)];
        //console.log(lineArrays.indexOf(landLine));
    
        $(".imageBox").animate({ //Maybe do something here with that random selected element.
            right: landLine
        }, {
            duration: 10500,
            easing: 'easeOutQuint'
        });



    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="roll">click</div>
<div class="imageBox" id="1"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="2"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="3"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="4"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="5"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="6"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="7"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="8"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="9"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="10"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="11"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="12"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="13"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="14"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="15"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="16"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="17"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="18"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="19"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="20"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="21"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="22"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="23"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="24"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="24"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="25"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="26"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="27"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="28"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="29"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="30"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="31"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="32"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="33"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="34"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="35"> <img src="image here"> </div>
  <div class="imageBox" id="36"> <img src="image here"> </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04465a44/)